# How to track if someone is remotely watching your network

Tags: wifi, router, netstat

How can i check that I am being remotely watched? This is the netstat results of my current network. Is someone able to check if someone is remotely stalking me?

Are there any suggestions on how I can make sure no one is securely watching my computer?

I check my router always, on "wireless clients" it never shows anyone but my phone or ipad connected. Also on "devices connected" it shows the same. Is there a possibility that a hacker can hide that he is connected to the router through this?

[image]

**I updated 1 minute after and the "connected devices" changed by a couple of devices**

[image]

```
Active Connections

Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1868
TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       800
TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1868
TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
TCP    0.0.0.0:13447          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1868
TCP    0.0.0.0:27036          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1784
TCP    0.0.0.0:49408          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       508
TCP    0.0.0.0:49409          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1016
TCP    0.0.0.0:49410          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       996
TCP    0.0.0.0:49411          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1344
TCP    0.0.0.0:49413          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       636
TCP    0.0.0.0:49416          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       644
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4396
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55640        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55641        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55642        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55643        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55644        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55645        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55646        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55647        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55648        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55649        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55654        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55655        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55656        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55657        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55658        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55659        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55660        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55661        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55662        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55663        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55664        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55665        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55666        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55667        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55668        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55669        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55670        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55671        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55672        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55673        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55678        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55679        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55680        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55682        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55683        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55684        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55685        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55700        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55703        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55704        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55705        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55706        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55707        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55708        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55709        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:1120         127.0.0.1:55710        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:50024        127.0.0.1:50025        ESTABLISHED     4396
TCP    127.0.0.1:50025        127.0.0.1:50024        ESTABLISHED     4396
TCP    127.0.0.1:51520        127.0.0.1:51521        ESTABLISHED     4396
TCP    127.0.0.1:51521        127.0.0.1:51520        ESTABLISHED     4396
TCP    127.0.0.1:53015        127.0.0.1:53016        ESTABLISHED     4396
TCP    127.0.0.1:53016        127.0.0.1:53015        ESTABLISHED     4396
TCP    127.0.0.1:55750        127.0.0.1:55751        ESTABLISHED     4396
TCP    127.0.0.1:55751        127.0.0.1:55750        ESTABLISHED     4396
TCP    127.0.0.1:57590        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5576
TCP    127.0.0.1:57976        127.0.0.1:57977        ESTABLISHED     4396
TCP    127.0.0.1:57977        127.0.0.1:57976        ESTABLISHED     4396
TCP    127.0.0.1:58548        127.0.0.1:58549        ESTABLISHED     5484
TCP    127.0.0.1:58549        127.0.0.1:58548        ESTABLISHED     5484
TCP    127.0.0.1:61021        127.0.0.1:61022        ESTABLISHED     4396
TCP    127.0.0.1:61022        127.0.0.1:61021        ESTABLISHED     4396
TCP    127.0.0.1:63947        127.0.0.1:63948        ESTABLISHED     4396
TCP    127.0.0.1:63948        127.0.0.1:63947        ESTABLISHED     4396
TCP    127.0.0.1:65353        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5576
TCP    127.0.0.1:65370        127.0.0.1:65371        ESTABLISHED     4396
TCP    127.0.0.1:65371        127.0.0.1:65370        ESTABLISHED     4396
TCP    192.168.0.11:139       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
TCP    192.168.0.11:50752     157.55.56.144:40022    ESTABLISHED     1868
TCP    192.168.0.11:50763     162.254.193.6:27020    ESTABLISHED     1784
TCP    192.168.0.11:50765     65.52.108.74:443       ESTABLISHED     1868
TCP    192.168.0.11:50855     40.122.162.208:443     ESTABLISHED     1868
TCP    192.168.0.11:50860     157.56.194.8:443       ESTABLISHED     1868
TCP    192.168.0.11:50883     24.105.29.40:443       CLOSE_WAIT      5484
TCP    192.168.0.11:50886     24.105.36.223:3724     ESTABLISHED     5484
TCP    192.168.0.11:50896     208.111.181.47:1119    CLOSE_WAIT      5484
TCP    192.168.0.11:51178     52.24.1.181:443        CLOSE_WAIT      2524
TCP    192.168.0.11:51383     24.105.36.229:3724     ESTABLISHED     5484
TCP    192.168.0.11:51464     173.194.198.188:5228   ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:51477     24.105.29.75:80        CLOSE_WAIT      4396
TCP    192.168.0.11:51553     151.101.1.69:443       ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:51555     209.148.192.26:80      ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:51560     151.101.65.69:80       ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:51579     104.16.112.18:443      TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    192.168.0.11:51606     151.101.1.69:80        ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:51612     151.101.1.69:80        ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:51661     23.195.195.38:443      ESTABLISHED     1868
TCP    192.168.0.11:51668     172.217.1.98:443       CLOSE_WAIT      1868
TCP    192.168.0.11:51671     172.217.3.130:443      CLOSE_WAIT      1868
TCP    192.168.0.11:51672     52.6.25.230:443        CLOSE_WAIT      1868
TCP    192.168.0.11:51677     207.244.67.198:443     CLOSE_WAIT      1868
TCP    192.168.0.11:51679     23.195.196.82:443      ESTABLISHED     1868
TCP    192.168.0.11:51682     23.195.196.82:443      ESTABLISHED     1868
TCP    192.168.0.11:51683     23.195.196.82:443      ESTABLISHED     1868
TCP    192.168.0.11:51684     23.195.196.82:443      ESTABLISHED     1868
TCP    192.168.0.11:51753     151.101.1.69:80        ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:51754     151.101.1.69:80        ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:51755     151.101.65.69:80       ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:51756     151.101.1.69:80        ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:51757     151.101.65.69:80       ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:51759     151.101.1.69:80        ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:51803     172.217.4.227:443      ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:54605     91.190.218.56:12350    ESTABLISHED     1868
TCP    192.168.0.11:55595     40.96.32.50:443        ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:55598     23.195.201.105:443     ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:55608     138.91.243.193:443     ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:55623     151.101.65.69:80       TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    192.168.0.11:55624     151.101.65.69:80       TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    192.168.0.11:55625     151.101.65.69:80       TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    192.168.0.11:55626     209.148.192.43:80      TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    192.168.0.11:55627     209.148.192.43:80      TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    192.168.0.11:55628     209.148.192.43:80      TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    192.168.0.11:55635     209.148.205.18:80      TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    192.168.0.11:55636     209.148.205.18:80      TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    192.168.0.11:55677     198.252.206.25:443     ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:55681     104.237.191.1:443      ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:55686     192.0.73.2:443         ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:55687     192.0.73.2:443         ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:55688     192.0.73.2:443         ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:55689     192.0.73.2:443         ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:55690     192.0.73.2:443         ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:55691     192.0.73.2:443         ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:55692     23.195.206.206:443     ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:55693     23.195.206.206:443     ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:55694     104.16.112.18:443      ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:55695     104.16.112.18:443      ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:55696     104.16.112.18:443      ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:55698     54.197.238.119:80      ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:55699     151.101.65.69:80       ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:55701     69.172.216.56:443      ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    192.168.0.11:55702     69.172.216.56:443      ESTABLISHED     6932
TCP    [::]:135               [::]:0                 LISTENING       800
TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
TCP    [::]:49408             [::]:0                 LISTENING       508
TCP    [::]:49409             [::]:0                 LISTENING       1016
TCP    [::]:49410             [::]:0                 LISTENING       996
TCP    [::]:49411             [::]:0                 LISTENING       1344
TCP    [::]:49413             [::]:0                 LISTENING       636
TCP    [::]:49416             [::]:0                 LISTENING       644
UDP    0.0.0.0:443            *:*                                    1868
UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*                                    6932
UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*                                    6932
UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*                                    6932
UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*                                    1172
UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*                                    1172
UDP    0.0.0.0:13447          *:*                                    1868
UDP    0.0.0.0:27036          *:*                                    1784
UDP    0.0.0.0:49309          *:*                                    1784
UDP    0.0.0.0:54509          *:*                                    6932
UDP    0.0.0.0:55387          *:*                                    6932
UDP    0.0.0.0:57722          *:*                                    6932
UDP    0.0.0.0:57724          *:*                                    6932
UDP    0.0.0.0:63730          *:*                                    1868
UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*                                    356
UDP    127.0.0.1:52598        *:*                                    356
UDP    127.0.0.1:55972        *:*                                    1868
UDP    192.168.0.11:137       *:*                                    4
UDP    192.168.0.11:138       *:*                                    4
UDP    192.168.0.11:1900      *:*                                    356
UDP    192.168.0.11:2177      *:*                                    356
UDP    192.168.0.11:52597     *:*                                    356
UDP    192.168.0.11:62534     *:*                                    6932
UDP    [::]:5353              *:*                                    6932
UDP    [::]:5353              *:*                                    6932
UDP    [::]:63730             *:*                                    1868
UDP    [::1]:1900             *:*                                    356
UDP    [::1]:52596            *:*                                    356
UDP    [fe80::38c6:1709:518d:3d19%4]:546 *:*                         1016
```

Comment: You say connected devices has changed, but I see the exact same three MAC addresses in both screenshots. And I don't see any connection between those screenshots and the netstat output. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe you are being 'watched'? There is nothing in your evidence to suggest it, and you seem to say that there is no evidence. So, I'm not sure what you expect us to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are concerned that someone might attach to your WiFi, ask yourself a few simple questions:

- Are you using WPA2 encryption instead of outdated WEP?
- Did you give your password to friends or neighbours?

With WPA2 and no one knowing your current password it is highly unlikely that someone would break into your WiFi router and attach a device. To make things more secure, you could set up an MAC-address based access list in the router (most of them should have it), which will only permit devices into the WiFi which you register with the router.

Finally hide your broadcasted SSID, also an option with most routers, so people would have to guess it.

While hiding your SSID can be worked around, it takes special tools or knowledge.

Remember that "stalking" is mostly driven by a personal interest, not by boredom of some lone hacker, and if you feel being followed it will almost always be someone who is close to you in some means. If you can´t identify such a person, get less frightened. Modern IT technology seems obscure but in most cases it does it´s job pretty well...

Comment: @Ashas: it is also possible to spoof a MAC address, this was the reason why I chose the wording as it was. But ok, let´s keep it like this.